# Waves - against the ship - verb?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Not waves crash against the ship, as the waves are gently; but I can´t find the verb for it.
Any ideas?

Comment: Lap, as in dance.

Comment: How would you use it in a sentence?

Comment: Waves lapped gently against the ship.

Comment: @Lap is the best but 'wash' could be used too.

Comment: Sloshed is another possubility.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Not as in lap dance or lap dog. As in: The dogs laps the water in the bowl.

Comment: Also beat, drummed, slapped.

Answer (score 1):

*The waves **lapped** the ship's hull.*

> **lap**<sup>3</sup> 2. (of water) wash against (something) with a gentle rippling sound.
>  <sub>*‘the waves lapped the shore’*</sub>
> <sub>Source:
> [Lexico—*lap*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/lap)</sub>

Note that the verb in this sense is considered transitive, which means an *object* will follow. Lapped *what*? Lapped *the shore* or lapped *the ship's hull*.

You will also encounter intransitive usages of *lap* (where *lap* is followed by—for example—a prepositional phrase: *The waves lapped **against the shore***).

For simplicity, your best bet is to consider *lap* to already contain the sense of *against*: Choose *The waves lapped the ship* or *The waves washed against the ship*, rather than *The waves lapped against the ship* or *The waves washed the ship* (unless you need a free shipwash).

Comment: The [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lap) seems to disagree with you about using a preposition with 'lapped' as it includes _"The water lapped against the side of the pool"_ as an example of use in its entry for 'lap'. In fact it defines the verb as either intransitive or transitive depending on context.

Comment: @BoldBen: Dictionaries disagree with one another too. Nonetheless, I'll buy the intransitive version. I modified my answer.